# add a number with the current number in database with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I have this code to update a payment record if it already exists, if not, just create new one, and it is working ..... but I need to add a new amount to the existing amount for the update case:

```
try {
    Payment::updateOrCreate([
        'user_id' => $request->users,
    ], [
        'amount' => $request->amount,
        'date' => $mytime,
        'number' => $number++,
    ]);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'you cannot insert this record');
}
```

Comment: When update is the case, `amount !== $request->amount`?

Answer (score 1):

What about using `firstOrNew` and doing something like this?
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models

```
try {
    $payment = Payment::firstOrNew([
        'user_id' => $request->users,
    ], [
        'amount' => $request->amount,
        'date' => $mytime,
        'number' => $number++,
    ]);

    if ($payment->id) {
       $payment->amount = $payment->amount + $new_amount;
    }
    
    $payment->save();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'you cannot insert this record');
}
```

- In case a model is found, you will have a payment instance id, then you manipulate the amount.
- For new Payment the model instance doesn't have an id then you just save the model.

Note that the model returned by `firstOrNew` has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to manually call the save method to persist it.